# Disable Junit5 tests based on file separator

Tags: java, annotations, junit5

I want to be able to disable a JUnit5 test based on the file seperator the `OS` uses.

For example the windows file seperator is `\` and a sample path would be `src\resources\fou`.

On another `OS` the file seperator could be `/` (maybe MAC?).
I want my test to run **only** when the file seperator is `\`.

I found this: `@EnabledIfSystemProperty(named = "file.separator", matches = "[/]")`
so i changed the `/` to `\` to match the windows file seperator, but it didn't work giving me this error:
`failed to evaluate condition`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Windows uses `\` as its file separator.

Thus, the following should result in the wanted behaviour.

```java
@Test
@EnabledOnOs(OS.WINDOWS)
void onlyOnWindows() {
    // ...
}
```

Copied from: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-conditional-execution-os

That said, you match a single backslash in Java via 4 (four) backslashes. This should also work:

```java
@EnabledIfSystemProperty(named = "file.separator", matches = "\\\\")
```

Comment: Silly mistake i used two \\. Should have gone for four. I thought that someone might change(do not know if that is actually possible) the file separator that's why i didn't want to check for the operating system.`@EnabledIfSystemProperty(named = "file.separator", matches = "\\\\")` works fine. Thanks.